# Setting Inno Setup sign tool with relative paths

Tags: installation, inno-setup, code-signing, signtool

I'm trying to set the Inno Setup IDE "Sign Tools" command to use a relative path.
I made a `sign.bat` script which calls `signtool.exe` following the file structure below:

```
code_sign\
          + sign.bat
          + signtool.exe
          + cert.pfx
script.iss
```

If I set the Sign Tool (`Tools / Configure Sign Tools...`) command to `code_sign\sign.bat $p`, I got the following error message:

```
   Sign Tool command failed (Failed to execute Sign Tool.

Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified). Will retry (2 tries left).
   Running Sign Tool command: sign.bat "(...)\uninst.e32.tmp"
   Sign Tool command failed (Failed to execute Sign Tool.
(...)
```

What is the working path when the sign tool is called?

Sadly I cannot use an absolute path (which works) as the `code_sign` folder is meant to be a submodule shared with other applications and other users.

What I'm doing wrong here? Should I use the command line version?

The `sign.bat` contents:

```
SET script_path=%~dp0
SET stool=%script_path%signtool.exe
SET pfx=%script_path%cert.pfx

SET ntp=http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll
SET pwd=12345

"%stool%" sign /f %pfx% /p %pwd% /tr %ntp% /td SHA256 %1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your sign tool command as only `$p`.

And then in your .iss, set the [`SignTool` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_signtool) as follows (assuming the sign tool command is named `custom`), with a use of `SourcePath` [preprocessor predefined variable](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=predefinedvars).

```
[Setup]
SignTool=custom {#SourcePath}\code_sign\sign.bat $f
```